# configure weblogic to accept oAuth Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, weblogic

We are looking step on- how to configure weblogic to accept oAuth Authentication.
We are using Apigee as identity provider, which is accepting now the oAuth authentication but our application is on weblogic server and weblogic have its own separate authentication. We do not want a double authentication mechanism and want weblogic also to accept the oAuth Authentication. Please suggest how to configure it.

WE have tried google suggestion, Oracle SR# etc

Comment: From my experience, the simplest is to use an http server in front of WebLogic, such as Apache HTTPD. Apache has a dedicated oAuth module. Next, you have to configure an identity asserter in WebLogic Server to trust tokens. The major part of authentication is then in charge of Apache and not WebLogic.

Comment: Can you please provide any step by step documentation or link? if any.